# Slide Toggle Class

Tags: jquery, css, overlay, transition

I have a toggle class for an overlay over a slide out menu.

The css styling for the overlay is:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
z-index: 9999;
```

And the jQuery for the toggle class is:

```
    $('#shiftnav-toggle-main-button, .shiftnav-panel-close').on('click', function(){ // On click on menu button or close button
$("#shiftnav-toggle-main-button").toggleClass('overlay', 500, 'easeIn'); 
});
```

The toggle class slides in when the menu is opened, but when the menu is closed, it just disappears, instead of sliding out. How can I get it to adhere to the css transition settings when the menu is closed?

Comment: You should set `easeIn` on element `easeOut` on class, or just set `ease` on element *(remove any ease from your jQuery code)*, also your button has not `width` and it just obtain `width` after `toggleClass` so you need to set a static width for your button.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes the menu does slide in and out, but the overlay doesn't. The overlay only slides in and then disappears out. It doesn't slide out smoothly with the menu.

And please excuse that I didn't add all relevant code involved, still new to the platform. Will definitely include it in future.

Comment: @Pedram I removed the ease on the jQuery code and kept the transition on the element only but the overlay is still not sliding out smoothly. And by setting a static width for my button, do you mean I should set a width for the menu button? I'm not sure how that will help the situation.

Answer (score 1):

It back to your code and yor *UI* logic, because you turn your button to overlay, so when your class has `width` but the element not, it won't play `transition` right.

Remove:

```
transition: all 0.5s ease-in !important;
```

From `.overlay` Then replace `.shiftnav-toggle` with:

```
.shiftnav-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in !important;
    width: 100px; // sample width and height
    height: 20px;
}
```

See the result to understand my first comment. But I highly recommend you to change your code, Instead of adding `width` to your element, add an `overlay` and do not turn your button to an overlay.

Comment: I see what you mean. I think the better option would have been to add an active class for the overlay that activates when the menu is opened instead of turning the button into an overlay.